# Ajax with flask for real time esque updates of sensor data on webpage

Tags: python, ajax, flask, settimeout

I've been trying to get this flask server to update itself with data generated from a loop that runs on a a .py script when called for by the user via push button on webpage. I've been looking into recommended solutions and have seen websockets (sockets.io), ajax, nodejs come up. I understand that i need to implement some form of js in my project, and ajax looked to be the most simple (so i thought). I only have about 3 weeks of experience programming in python. Mainly i look for examples close to what i want, and then try to modify it to suit my needs, but haven't found any examples for what i'm looking for. Even then, my general newness to programming means that the more examples i "tack on" the more likely i am to degrade the overall structure of what i've already accomplished.

**Goal**

The goal is to update a value displayed on the page without a reload but instead have js update the value every second. The value is generated from a x=x+1 counter in my .py file. This will be replaced by sensor inputs gathered from my Rpi later.

**Actual results**

When i run the current code,

1. my html elements get double posted so i see what i've put into the index.html file twice although the second button elements don't actually respond to clicking,
2. I also get an endless stream of Posts in my terminal window.
3. Clicking on the button elements no longer execute my loop in the .py file and instead displays "Method not allowed"

**What i've tried**

I've tried to implement setTmeout in my html file as a way to call back to the python app and get an updated value (the x=x+1) every second. I've read posts around using setTimeout as a way to deal with issues using setInterval. Due to the variety of ways i've seen ajax calls employed and learning resources being primarily structured towards forms, databases, and chat apps, most of my searches aren't bringing up anything new for me to learn from that might help. I'm currently doing ajax tutorials hoping to come accross something i can use, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ajaxTest.py My python flask file**

```
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
app = Flask(__name__)

bioR_on = False
ledGrnSts = 0
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
air = 21
light = 20
waste = 16
feed = 12
water = 26
pinList = [21,20,16,12,26] 

def pump(pin):
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
        print(pin,'on')
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        print(pin, 'off')
        time.sleep(1)

def on(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

@app.route("/")
def index(): 
    templateData = {
              'title' : 'Bioreactor output Status!',
              'ledGrn'  : ledGrnSts,
        }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

@app.route('/<deviceName>/<action>', methods = ["POST"])
def start(deviceName, action):
    # script for Pi Relays
    def run():
        if action == "on":
            alarm = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds =10)
            global bioR_on
            bioR_on = True

            while bioR_on:

                tday = datetime.now()
                time.sleep(1)
                #feed(tday, alarm)
                x=x+1
                return jsonify(x)
                GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

                for i in pinList:
                    GPIO.setup (i, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
                on(air)
                on(light)
                print(tday)
                if tday >= alarm:
                    print('alarm activated')
              #  run = False
                    pump(waste)
                    print('waste activated')
                    pump(feed)
                    print('feed on')
                    GPIO.cleanup()
                    alarm = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds =10)
                    print('next feeding time ', alarm)
                    time.sleep(1)
        if action == 'off':
            bioR_on = False
            #return "off"
            GPIO.cleanup()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()

    templateData = {
            'ledGrn'  : ledGrnSts,
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

**My index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>BioReactor Control</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href='../static/style.css'/>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1>Actuators</h1>
        <h2> Status </h2>
        <h3> GRN LED ==>  {{ ledGrn  }}</h3>
        <br>
        <h2> Commands </h2>
        <h3> 
            Activate Bioreactor Ctrl ==> 
            <a href="/bioR/on" class="button">TURN ON</a>  
            <a href="/bioR/off"class="button">TURN OFF</a>
        </h3>
        <h3>
            Current Count 
        </h3>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
                    setTimeout($.ajax({
                        url: '/<deviceName>/<action>',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            $("#num").html(response);
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    }), 1000);


        </script>
        <h1>Output</h1>
        <h1 id="num"></h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Picture of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9vnW.jpg)

Comment: links `<a href="/bioR/on">` `<a href="/bioR/off"` are send as `GET` to `route('/<deviceName>/<action>', methods = ["POST"])` but you accept only `POST` - you need `methods = ["GET", "POST"]`

Comment: you JavaScript send request to route which runs again and again new Thread - so every minute it create 60 threads. If you want to update value then you should rather send post to function which only send back current value.

Comment: BTW: `return` always ends function so all after `return jsonify(x)` is never executed. if you want to do something elses then you have to do before `return jsonify(x)`. Other problem that `return` will ends your `while bioR_on:` loop so there is no sense to run it in loop. Besides nobody can get values created with `return jsonify(x)` because you run it in thread. Maybe assign it to global varialbe or uses queue to send it to main thread.

Comment: `JavaScript` sends `POST` to `route('/<deviceName>/<action>'` which sends back `return render_template('index.html'...)` not `return jsonify(x)` - and this way you get `index.html` two or many times - and it probably runs two or many times the same `JavaScript` which sends more `POST` to `route('/<deviceName>/<action>'` - so finally it runs script many times in one second instead of running it only once every 1 second.

Comment: shortly: you use one function `start` in Flask for all job but you should have separted functions. Current function  `start` should be used only with buttons (and with method `GET`) but `AJAX` should use some new function with separate `url` - ie. `/update` - which sends new value `x` or `jsonify(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created minimal code which uses `AJAX` to get new value every 1 second.

I use `setInterval` to repeate it every 1 second. I also uses `function(){ $.ajax ... }` to create function which is not executed at once but `setInterval` will call it every 1 second. Without `function(){...}` code `$.ajax` was executed at start and its result was used as function executed  every 1 second - but it returns nothing - so finally it updated value only once (at start) and later `setInterval` was running nothing.

I added current time to see if it is still running.

`buttons` run function `'/<device>/<action>'` which start and stop thread but `AJAX` uses  `/update` to get current value.

I use `render_template_string` to have all code in one file - so other people can easily copy and test it.

I reduced HTML to minimal. To make sure I put `<h1>` before script which needs these tags.

I didn't tested it with `global=True` which may run it in new threads and it can make problem.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify
import datetime
import time
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

running = False # to control loop in thread
value = 0       

def rpi_function():
    global value

    print('start of thread')
    while running: # global variable to stop loop  
        value += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    print('stop of thread')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<device>/<action>')
def index(device=None, action=None):
    global running
    global value

    if device:
        if action == 'on':
            if not running:
                print('start')
                running = True
                threading.Thread(target=rpi_function).start()
            else:
                print('already running')
        elif action == 'off':
            if running:
                print('stop')
                running = False  # it should stop thread
            else:
                print('not running')

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <a href="/bioR/on">TURN ON</a>  
        <a href="/bioR/off">TURN OFF</a>
        <h1 id="num"></h1>
        <h1 id="time"></h1>
        <script>
            setInterval(function(){$.ajax({
                url: '/update',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#num").html(response["value"]);
                    $("#time").html(response["time"]);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })}, 1000);
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
''')

@app.route('/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    return jsonify({
        'value': value,
        'time': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
    })

app.run() #debug=True
```

Comment: Furas, thank you so much for your time working on this. This reponse is above and beyond what i was expecting. You not only gave me a working example to play with, but also broke down what was wrong with my previous code for me so that i can learn. I'll be sure to mention your contribution to this work when i make it open access! Many thanks

Comment: @ThunkTank you can upvote in addition to accepting the answer, you know.